# How to set the event name for server sent events (SSE) in Quarkus

Tags: server-sent-events, quarkus

I have following Quarkus resource:

```
@Path("/myResource")
class MyResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/eventStream")
    @Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    @SseElementType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun stream(): Multi<MyDto> = deviceStatusService.getStream()
}
```

This will produce events without event name and only the data section.
How can I specify an event name?

Comment: Can you specify where you want to add naming for events? You want to subscribe for different events on frontend or split events on backend?

Comment: The SSE specs allows for [named events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events). I want to split events on the frontend using e.g. `evtSource.addEventListener("someEvent", (e) => alert(e.data))`

Comment: Feels like it's not implemented in resteasy library(or maybe I don't know about it), If it's time critical for you you can try to use non-reactive approach as in this document: https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.5.1.Final/userguide/html/JAX-RS_2.1_additions.html#d4e1400
You can use sink and sse object to send events, basically your method will be void, and you'll need to subscribe to your stream there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My final code is now:

```kotlin
    @GET
    @Path("/eventStream")
    @Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    @SseElementType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun stream(@Context sse: Sse, @Context sseEventSink: SseEventSink) {
        deviceStatusService.getStream().subscribe().with { deviceStatus ->
            sseEventSink.send(sse.newEventBuilder()
                        .name("deviceStatus")
                        .data(deviceStatus)
                        .build())
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As per comments to the question, looks like it's not implemented in Resteasy library, One option is to use non-reactive approach e.g

```kotlin
    @GET
    @Path("/eventStream")
    @Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    @SseElementType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun stream(@Context sse: Sse, @Context sseEventSink: SseEventSink) { 
        return deviceStatusService.getStream().subscribe().asIterable().forEach { it -> sseEventSink.send(sse.newEvent("myEvent", it.toString()))}
    }
```

You can use `OutboundSseEventImpl.BuilderImpl()` to build event with json object.
Although, again, it's a temporary solution

Answer (score 0):

You have to return a `Multi\<OutboundSseEvent\>`

```kotlin
@GET
@RestStreamElementType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
fun stream(@Context sse: Sse): Multi<OutboundSseEvent> {
  return quotes.map {
    sse.newEventBuilder()
      .data(it)
      .name("update")
      .build()
  }
}
```

The entire class is here

https://github.com/eduardo-villasboas/quarkus-poc/blob/server-sent-events/src/main/kotlin/quarkus/producer/QuotesProducer.kt

The client is here on the same project

https://github.com/eduardo-villasboas/quarkus-poc/blob/server-sent-events/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/quotes.html